# Barcode Scanner Application with Precursor ALT+F12 randomly truncating barcode

Tags: barcode, barcode-scanner

Over the years we've heard a small few of complaints about the barcode scanner not always reading the barcodes successfully, and until recently debugging another issue I caught the problem in debugger to see whats going on.

Our app listens for the ALT+F12 keypress which the barcode scanner sends before the keytag string followed by ENTER.

When I was able to reproduce this, I was using a barcode "FC0209083" and while in debugger, I noticed when the scan actually failed on me, that all the numeric digits were truncated leaving the barcode read as "FC" instead of the full length barcode.

I was able to reproduce this a few times, but nothing was consistent. I was playing around with having taskbar, taskbar app preview, desktop, various windows and menus in focus instead of our application.

I think the problem may possibly be focusing an app or window that also has the ALT+F12 hotkey of some sort. So far I'm at a loss, and it doesn't happen vary often and haven't been able to find a definite way to reproduce the issue 100% of the time.

**Edit: Any idea what would be causing the scanned text to be truncated in this manner, or a definite way to work around this with a keyboard wedge?**

Comment: Was there a specific question in here somewhere?

Comment: My apologies, there was a problem explained that I need to get around, but no not an actual question.

Any idea what would be causing the scanned text to be truncated in this manner, or a definite way to work around this with a keyboard wedge?